# iOS - xcode 4.5 doesn't execute the first instruction of the AppDelegate application method

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

I need tips to debug an application, it just shows a black screen but it doesn't execute a single instruction of the application method in the AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOption:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
      // Override point for customization after application launch.

  NSLog(@"This log is not displayed!?");

  OMManager *manager=[[EMCore getInstance] manager];
  [manager managedObjectModel];
  if([manager applicationLogDirectory]==nil){
    NSLog(@"Application Log is nil");
    exit(1);
  }

  NSString * pass=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"PASSWORD"];
  //UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
  NSString *storyboardName=pass==nil?@"Login_iPhone":@"Main_iPhone";

  UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *controller=[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
  [self setWindow:[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds]];
  [[self window] setRootViewController:controller];
  [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
```

It was working all fine. I was loading the storyboard and then the initial view controller perfectly until I tried to add the Core Data. I added it in a singleton that I use in several points of the code. But when I run the code it doesn't show any error (it compiles correctly), it just starts and show the black screen. I removed the lines where I try to load the core data and it is the same, it doesn't nothing. Just in case I added the libraries required by the CoreData I think correctly. I have a log also inside the singleton and it neither is executed, so the problem must be elsewhere.

My question is: What happens before AppDelegate:application call? Where I can add a log or something to start the debug and try to understand what is happening here?

*PS: obviously I have the log screen opened :P*

Comment: Is it really `didFinishLaunchingWithOption:` in your code? It should be `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: Hell, you are right, I deleted somehow the -s I'm searching for a tree to hang me. I was turning mad here. thank you so much Julien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd override applicationDidEnterForeground and you an do you debugging in there.

Also in your MainWindow.xib, your application delegate object may not connected to File's Owner (UIApplication). Open MainWindow.xib and click on your App Delegate to see if it has a connection in Referencing Outlet to File's Owner, and if not set it.

Comment: I use storyboards I don't have any MainWindow.xib file. applicationDidEnterForeground is executed, and I can place a breakpoint there. But I still don't understand why the application method is not executed.

Comment: you could even do some debugging in main.m. Your main.m contains the main() function, which is the entry point for the program, it's run first. Then it calls UIApplicationMain(), which does the OS-specific application setup stuff, and loads the main Interface Builder .xib file which contains your app delegate instance. Just some info. But I agree, it is peculiar it's not working. Do a complete clean and refresh, and delete the app off your device/simulator as well. You may also have to manually clear your temporary files on your mac.

Comment: I still don't get it, in fact it enters to applicationDidEnterForeground I followed it step by step in the low level instructions of the debugger. It never enters in any class wrote by me, but it just keeps running without enters in application method. What can prevent it? Any clue?

Comment: OK I reset the simulator, same result, nothing new happened. My main file is the default provided by the Xcode, pretty simple call: return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([EMAppDelegate class]));

Comment: Where are the temporary files that you suggest me to clean?

Comment: NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSLog(@"tempDir='%@'", tempDir);

Comment: ok the mystery has been solved, I deleted somehow the ending -s from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions... no comments O_O"

Comment: lol.. haha. that'll definitely do it, Piotr! Sorry for not catching it. Happy coding.